# Operator Precedence

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I tried to compute this as `i=i*++i` therefore `i=56*57` which gives me 3192 but my program says the value is 2162:

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        short i=056;  
        i*=++i;  
        System.out.println(i);  
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you interested in - `i = i * ++i` or `i *= ++i`?

Comment: Remove the leading `0` from `056`, then you will notice something and probabley get the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is before the multiplication - it's here:

```
short i=056;
```

That's an *octal* literal, with decimal value 46. So you're actually getting the results of 46  * 47, which is indeed 2162.

I would *strongly* advise you not to use code like `i *= ++i` though. It's simpler for everyone concerned to use `i *= i + 1`. I'd also advise you not to use octal literals.

Comment: I'd also strongly advise not to use octal literals!

Comment: @Gabe: Did that about 30 seconds ago :)